# Family tree with multiple parents and different line types

Tags: html, tree

Im trying to create a simple family tree using HTML (I also could include CSS and Javascript if needed). I would like to achieve something like this:

http://www.gmrv.es/~sschvartzman/Sara_C._Schvartzman/example.png

Does anybody know how I can make this?

EDIT:

The structure from which Im constructing this webpage is of the type:

```
Father
Mother
n Number of children
children[n]
```

I want to construct this figure automatically. I want each person to have a link to another webpage, but I think this will be easy once I have the figure.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally managed to create a multiple parent family tree diagram.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta name="description" content=""><meta name="author" content=""><link href="tree.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Family Tree</title> </head><body> <h1>Schvartzman family tree</h1>
<div class="tree">
    <ul class="pf">
        <li class="parent">
            <a  class="f_nolink">
                <div class="person"">Claudia<br>Avila<span>(1961 - )</span></div> 
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="divorce">
            <ul class="c">              <li>
                    <a  class="m_nolink">
                        <div class="person"">Sebastian<br>Berdichevsky<span>(1981 - )</span></div> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="@F62327212@.html" class="f">
                        <div class="person"">Sara<br>Berdichevsky<span>(1986 - )</span></div> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  class="m_nolink">
                        <div class="person"">Manuel<br>Berdichevsky<span>(1987 - )</span></div> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  class="m_nolink">
                        <div class="person"">Sergio<br>Berdichevsky<span>(1989 - )</span></div> 
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentWithAncestor">
            <a href="@F62638334@.html" class="m">
                <div class="person"">Eduardo<br>Berdichevsky<span>(1961 - )</span></div> 
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="marriage">
            <ul class="c">              <li>
                    <a  class="f_nolink">
                        <div class="person"">Abigail<br>Berdichevsky<span>(2001 - )</span></div> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  class="m_nolink">
                        <div class="person"">Tobias<br>Berdichevsky<span>(2003 - )</span></div> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  class="m_nolink">
                        <div class="person"">Iamin<br>Berdichevsky<span>(2007 - )</span></div> 
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <a  class="f_nolink">
                <div class="person"">Carolina<br>Overlar<span>(1978 - )</span></div> 
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<br>
</body> </html>
```

using a CSS file:

```
.tree * {margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {

    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    background-color:#fff;

}

.tree{
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 250px;
}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 5px; position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size:0;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    /*float: left; */
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 70px 5px 0 5px;
    font-size: 12px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 70px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
/*
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}
*/
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


.tree li li:only-child::before {
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right:none;
}
/*
.tree ul.p>li::before {
    border:none;
    content: '&';
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    }

.tree ul.p>li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: none;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

.tree ul.p>li::after{
    border-left: none;
}
*/
/* Use pf to indicate that its a child of another family. */
.tree ul.pf>li::before {
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right:none;
    }

.tree ul.pf>li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: none;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

.tree ul.pf>li::after{
    border-left: none;
}



/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul.c {
    padding-top: 70px; 
    }


.tree ul ul.c::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
    border: none;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    background-color:#fff;
    /*background-image:url(circle.jpg)*/
    /*color: #fff;
    background-color:#999;*/
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:50px;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;


    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* red border on contacts
.tree li a.o{
    border: 1px solid #f66;
}
*/

.tree li a span{
    display:block;
    font-size: 10px;

}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
/*.tree li a.m:hover { background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }   
.tree li a.f:hover { background: #ffc0cb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; } 

.tree li a:hover+ul li a.m { background: #c8e4fb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; } 
.tree li a:hover+ul li a.f { background: #ffc0cb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; } 

.tree li a.md:hover { background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }    
.tree li a.fd:hover { background: #ffc0cb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }    

.tree li a:hover+ul li a.md { background: #c8e4fb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }    
.tree li a:hover+ul li a.fd { background: #ffc0cb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }*/  

.tree li a.m{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:15px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #c8e4fb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:50px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #ffc0cb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.m_dead{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:15px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #F1F9FE; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f_dead{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:50px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #FFF0F2;box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.m_nolink{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:15px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #c8e4fb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f_nolink{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:50px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #ffc0cb; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.m_dead_nolink{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:15px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #F1F9FE; box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}
.tree li a.f_dead_nolink{width:80px;height:80px;border-radius:50px;font-size:10px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #FFF0F2;box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000}

.tree li.marriage{ height:0px; border: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000; color: #000; padding: 0 ; background: #FFF; }
.tree li.marriage::before{border: none}
.tree li.divorce{ height:0px; border: 2px; border-style: dashed; border-color: #000; color: #000; padding: 0 ; background: #FFF; }
.tree li.divorce::before{border: none}
.tree  ul.pf>li.parent::before{border: none}
.tree  ul.pf>li.parentWithAncestor::before{border-top: none;}

.tree div.person
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:central;
    padding:20px 0px;
    width:80px; 
}
/*
.tree li a.m:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #c8e4fb; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
.tree li a.f:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #ffc0cb; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
.tree li a.m_dead:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:15px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #F1F9FE; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
.tree li a.f_dead:hover{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;background: #FFF0F2; box-shadow:0 0 4px #222 inset}
*/
/*.tree li a.m { background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; } 
.tree li a.f { background: #ffc0cb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }   

.tree li a.md { background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }  
.tree li a.fd { background: #ffc0cb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }  

.tree li a+ul li a.m { background: #c8e4fb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }   
.tree li a+ul li a.f { background: #ffc0cb; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; }*/ 


/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I started it for you, just so you get the picture. You should be able to get the rest yourself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Diagram</title></head>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1260" height="765">
    <defs
     id="defs4">
    <linearGradient
         id="linearGradient5189"
         osb:paint="solid">
        <stop
             style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;"
             offset="0"
             id="stop5191" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

<metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
        <cc:Work
             rdf:about="">
            <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
            <dc:type
                 rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
            <dc:title></dc:title>
        </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g

     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-287.36218)">
    <rect
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:23.50000000000000000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         id="rect2985"
         width="236.3757"
         height="236.3757"
         x="125.25892"
         y="132.6445"
         transform="translate(0,287.36218)" />
    <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:23.88199997;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
         d="M 246.47723,713.3291 245.60768,587.95193 244.45692,422.02699"
         id="path5199"
         sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
    <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:25;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:75,25;stroke-dashoffset:105"
         d="m 793.9799,471.04561 -545.48237,0"
         id="path5246"
         transform="translate(0,287.36218)" />
    <path
         sodipodi:type="arc"
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:25;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:105"
         id="path5248"
         sodipodi:cx="717.71338"
         sodipodi:cy="259.41864"
         sodipodi:rx="122.73354"
         sodipodi:ry="122.73354"
         d="m 840.44692,259.41864 a 122.73354,122.73354 0 1 1 -245.46708,0 122.73354,122.73354 0 1 1 245.46708,0 z"
         transform="translate(68.690373,264.12867)" />
    <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:25;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
         d="m 787.87838,398.79348 0,-72.73098"
         id="path5250" />
    <image
         y="652.83923"
         x="775.43933"
         id="image5271"
         xlink:href=

"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAABiCAYAAAClDHhhAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAElJREFU
aIHtzUENACAMBLCDoGn+FWGBeSDZrzXQleRl2J4OJBKJRCKRSCQSiUQikUgkEolEIpFIJBKJRCKR
SCQSiUTy5VTVnU4aD+ADVQ9kdZUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
"
         height="117.1929"
         width="25" />
    <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:26.86911964;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
         d="m 245.97214,741.68118 0,16.7063"
         id="path5274" />
    <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:25;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         d="m 126.65969,249.12565 234.84816,2.63875"
         id="path5314"
         transform="translate(0,287.36218)" />
</g>

</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is nice, but its a family tree, so I will have to make many of these html pages, and it has to be automatic. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: @Sara yes there is, but in order to answer (and probably why you got a low vote) you have to expand your question. For example, what does your data structure look like?

Comment: Maybe I can use your code to construct the family automatically. I will try. Thanks!